# How can I declare a Two-dimensional arrray with an (int, char) pair value in java?

Tags: java, arrays, dimensional

I´m reading how to make a transition table for a NFA. I´m using java and according to my book in order to make the transition table for my NFA I need a two-dimensional array move[s,a] I assume a state s will be an integer and a a symbol from the input (Correct me if I´m wrong). The entries in this table, which are sets of states, are represented
by linked lists.

I don´t really know how to declare this on java because arrays can only be of one type.

I´ve been trying with

```
int[][] move
```

and

```
Arraylist<Integer>[][]
```

But I can´t find the way to map a string symbol to a set of integers. What I would ideally want to accomplish is that I enter for example: `move[5,"a"]` and get back a set of states (ints) like `[5,6,7,9]`

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: What have you tried? If you have a piece of code that runs but doesn't do what you want it to, you're welcome to come back and ask for help with the actual code.

Comment: I´ve been trying with int[][] move, and Arraylist<Integer>[][]. But I can´t find the way to map a string symbol to a set of integers. What I would ideally want to accomplish is that I enter for example: move[5,"a"] and get back a set of states (ints) like [5,6,7,9] .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
public class Entry  {
    public int s;
    public String symbol;
}
```

then

```
LinkedList<Entry>[][]  twoDimensional;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. That seem like a good aproach, but I don´t know if it´s a good idea to have the symbols as part of an entry, since the entry shoul just be the states of the NFA. I thinks it should be a way to do it without creating new objects

Comment: @PabloEstrada: You're going to need the class "Entry" somewhere to link a letter and (a) number(s).  Maybe making Entry's int s an array (or linked list) of integers rather than one, then taking a dimension off the main array would get you closer.

Answer (score 0):

Just use two different one dimensional arrays. If that won't work, use a HashMap.